# What's the rationale behind not parsing HTML entities in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, html-entities

It seems [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) that [HTML entities are not parsed in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61871/when-clicking-the-permalink-in-chat-html-entities-are-wrongly-escaped). What's the rationale for this?

In my humble opinion, HTML entities can be very useful. I would be able to freely type "—" with `&mdash;` and "–" with `&ndash;` instead of looking up their Unicode, instead of the really short and annoying hyphen. Heck, the minus sign is itself larger than a hyphen.

So, what is the rationale behind not allowing HTML entities? If it's potential for abuse, wouldn't it be better to disallow posting a message containing nothing but `&nbsp;`<sup>1</sup>? Or is there some other reason these aren't parsed?

---

1: Even so, people can easily post empty messages, so this is not a great counter.

Comment: To keep people from typing silly dashes like — and –. Make real sentences, you crazy dash person!

Comment: @Jason Here's a sentence: **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻️️️

Comment: Great question. Mdash is my favorite punctuation mark.

Comment: I *do* have to admit to a love of `&rarr;`, myself... Btw as for "abuse" (although I really don't see an issue that can't be solved with a flag if it's truly a problem) another approach would be to explicitly whitelist certain entities, rather than parsing them all. We really don't need `&shy;` in chat, for example.

Comment: I left my reply as a voice message: ▶ ──────── 00:33

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your question but I threw together a [quick userscript to add a couple characters I thought of to chat](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/ChatSpecialChars.user.js):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Special characters in chat
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/305991
// @version      1
// @description  Add buttons for special characters to chat
// @author       Jason C
// @match        *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        *://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        *://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/11077016 (thanks!):
    function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {
            myField.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
        }
        //MOZILLA and others
        else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
            var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
            myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
            myField.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            myField.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        } else {
            myField.value += myValue;
        }
    }

    function insertContent (content) {
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        insertAtCursor(input, content);
        input.focus();
    }

    function createButton (label, content) {
        var buttons = document.getElementById('chat-buttons');
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        //button.textContent = label;
        button.textContent = content; // I kind of like this as the label more.
        button.setAttribute('class', 'button');
        button.onclick = function () { insertContent(content); };
        buttons.appendChild(button);
        buttons.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
    }

    // use fromCharCode instead of actual chars because there seems to be encoding
    // issues when transferring from github to tampermonkey.
    createButton('ndash', String.fromCharCode(8211));
    createButton('mdash', String.fromCharCode(8212));
    createButton('rarr', String.fromCharCode(8594));

})();
```

This will add some buttons to chat which you can click to insert the character into the text box:

[image]

I've only tested it on Chrome. If you've got a compelling reason for me to add other characters to the git version let me know. You can also customize the code pretty easily.

Comment: Nice. [Porkchat](http://stackapps.com/questions/6266/porkchat-a-chrome-extension-with-lots-of-chat-tweaks) has a handy list of characters beside "upload", the only downside of which is it not being scrollable. I was thinking you could make these another list-like thing?